# How to select a single value from a column and use partition by to replicated over another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition-by

I want to create a new column called NewHeight that takes the single value found in the Height column and replicates it for all the same Name.
This is the query I am using.

```
Select 
Name,
Height,
case when Height is not null then max(Height) over(partition by Name) end as NewHeight
from MyTable
```

This is my output:

```
Name    Height  NewHeight
Johny       
Johny   5.6      5.6
Johny       
Mike        
Mike        
Mike    6.1      6.1
```

This is desired output :

```
Name    Height  NewHeight
Johny            5.6
Johny   5.6      5.6
Johny            5.6
Mike             6.1
Mike             6.1
Mike    6.1      6.1
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `is not null` when you should be using `is null`.  But, `coalesce()` is more concise:

```
Select Name, Height,
       coalesce(Height, max(Height) over (partition by Name) end as NewHeight
from MyTable;
```

Or, if you want the same value on each row, you don't even need conditional logic:

```
Select Name, Height,
       max(Height) over (partition by Name) as NewHeight
from MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()` :

```
Select  Name, Height,
        coalesce(Height, max(Height) over(partition by Name)) as NewHeight
from MyTable
```